# Pandas dataframe setting cell to NaN

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter, nan

I have created a dataframe like this:

```
    A  B
0  aa  1
1  bb  2
2  cc  3
3  dd  1
4  ee  1
```

then I used this line to insert a label:

```
df['label']= np.where((df['B']>2),'start',np.NaN)
```

result is

```
    A  B  label
0  aa  1    nan
1  bb  2    nan
2  cc  3  start
3  dd  1    nan
4  ee  1    nan
```

which is fairly straight forward. However when I try to counter-check my table, I cannot get the 'nan' rows.

```
df[(df.label.isnull())]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, label]
Index: []

df[(df.label.isna())]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, label]
Index: []

df[(df.label == np.nan)]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, label]
Index: []
```

I only get the nan rows by using this:

```
df[(df.label == 'nan')]
    A  B label
0  aa  1   nan
1  bb  2   nan
3  dd  1   nan
4  ee  1   nan
```

Did I do something wrong by incorrectly making the null values to be a string value 'nan'? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `np.where` converted `np.NaN` to a string because *start* is a string:

```
np.where((df['B']>2), 'start', np.NaN)

#array(['nan', 'nan', 'start', 'nan', 'nan'],
#      dtype='|S32')
```

Provide `None` as the null value for strings:

```
df['label'] = np.where((df['B']>2), 'start', None)

df[df.label.isnull()]

#    A  B   label
#0  aa  1   None
#1  bb  2   None
#3  dd  1   None
#4  ee  1   None
```

Or use `pd.Series.where` method:

```
df['label'] = 'start'
df['label'] = df.label.where(df.B > 2)
df[df.label.isnull()]

#   A   B   label
#0  aa  1   NaN
#1  bb  2   NaN
#3  dd  1   NaN
#4  ee  1   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply:

```
df['label'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'start' if x.B>2 else np.nan, axis=1)

df[(df.label.isnull())]
Out[135]: 
    A  B label
0  aa  1   NaN
1  bb  2   NaN
3  dd  1   NaN
4  ee  1   NaN
```

Or:

```
df['label'] = df.B.gt(2).apply({True:'start',False:np.nan}.get)
```